# Create a Cosmos Db and Container in C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to create a database and container using C# I am trying to use the newest version of `Azure.ResourceManager.CosmosDB 1.2.0`.

In a previos version I used:

```
var client = new CosmosDBManagementClient("someendpoint", new DefaultAzureCredential());
var database = await client.SqlResources.StartCreateUpdateSqlDatabaseAsync(
    AzureResourceGroup, AccountName, DatabaseName, 
    new SqlDatabaseCreateUpdateParameters(
        new SqlDatabaseResource(DatabaseName), 
        new CreateUpdateOptions()
    )
);

var armcontainer = await client.SqlResources.StartCreateUpdateSqlContainerAsync(
    AzureResourceGroup, AccountName, DatabaseName,
    ContainerName, 
    GetContainerParameters()
);
```

However, the `CosmosDBManagementClient` is no longer in library.

I know there is:

```
var client = new CosmosClient(endpoint, new DefaultAzureCredential());

await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync("testing", 
    throughput: null, new RequestOptions());
```

I also can't get this to work due to 403 error, even with the contributor permissions, but I know this was an error because you are supposed to use the resource manager.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: To use CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync you can use CosmosClient as long as you use one of the connection strings.  You cannot use DefaultAzureCredential.  This is obscurely mentioned in the docs for CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync.  Why they can't just say "connection string" instead of "master key" boggles my mind.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with passwordless access but have you tried providing the id explictely?

```
string userAssignedClientId = "<your managed identity client Id>";
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = userAssignedClientId });
var client = new CosmosClient(endpoint, new DefaultAzureCredential());
```

If this doesn't work you could try the connection string approach:

```
using CosmosClient client = new(
    accountEndpoint: "endpoint here",
    authKeyOrResourceToken: "key here");
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, while using the databse key works with Cosmos DB client, according to the trouble shooting pages it isn't supported to the DefaultAzureCredentials "Perform the operation through Azure Resource Manager, Azure portal, Azure CLI, or Azure PowerShell. If you are using the Azure Functions Azure Cosmos DB Trigger make sure the CreateLeaseContainerIfNotExists property of the trigger isn't set to true. Using Azure AD identities blocks any non-data operation, such as creating the lease container." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/troubleshoot-forbidden